# How do you work around Izotope Iris losing it's midi controller assignments?

Tags: midi, controller

I've been testing a demo of Izotope Iris and it keeps losing the Midi assignments (via Midi Learn button) after reboots and loading it in Ableton Live. It doesn't seem to save the settings correctly. Since it's a demo I've not contacting Izotope yet.. and there's not iris forum afaik.

Besides taking a screenshot and re-assigning it a lot of times, is there a way to work around this issue?

Comment: Hard to fully eliminate possibilities… whether it's the demo itself, or would still be the same in the full version, or indeed whether Ableton should be storing them. Can you test on another DAW?

Comment: hmm.. do you have 2.0 or 2.01? Release notes mentions Midi CC fix - https://www.izotope.com/en/support/support-resources/latest-product-updates/iris-2-release-notes/

Comment: Thanks, not at the studio right now. Will check which version it is.